# How add new item in existing collection in magento 2

Tags: collection, combine

i have 2 collections

**1**

```
Orders  
0   
date    "2019-07-05"
count   "2"
1   
date    "2019-06-20"
count   "2"
2   
date    "2019-06-18"
count   "2"
3   
date    "2019-06-17"
count   "2"
4   
date    "2019-06-14"
count   "1"
```

**2**

```
Amount  
0   
date    "2019-07-05"
sum "6370.00000000"
1   
date    "2019-06-20"
sum "6491.00000000"
2   
date    "2019-06-18"
sum "4838.00000000"
3   
date    "2019-06-17"
sum "4838.00000000"
4   
date    "2019-06-14"
sum "1653.00000000"
```

In both collections looking **date** is Same . i want to **sum** index of **second collection add in first collection** and it make only **one collection**

how can do this . 
i tried **$collection->addItem($collection2)** it not work

Comment: you can use join query here to achive your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Collection it's just a flexible select query to some table in your DB.
If you want to fetch some data or filter it - you may use methods like addFieldTofilter()
You may also use custom sql SELECT with conditions like ( ... WHERE table1.data = table2.data) but it will be very controversial decision.